# Where can I download a raster dataset with the latitude and longitude of each pixel in geographic projection?

Tags: qgis, raster, latitude-longitude

I want to do raster calculations in QGIS based on the latitude and longitude of each pixel.  The calculations will compute the area of the pixel, but also do other calculations for various projections of land masses.

The QGIS raster calculation facility does not appear to support variables for the X and Y coordinates (if it did, I could simply calculate the lat and long from the raster file metadata).

My raster maps are at 0.5 minute resolution, so a grid dataset of this resolution or better would be desirable.

The existence of many related questions on StackExchange indicate to me that there is a general need for a file such as I describe.  On the other hand, maybe there is an easy way to create such a file within QGIS.  That would be fine too.

Comment: Follow this logic to create a point layer. Then it is trivial to get lat/long from the point layer. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77306/how-to-convert-raster-to-point-in-qgis

Comment: what do you mean by 0.5 minutes resolution?
Did you mean 0.5 m or 50 cm?